# Never receiving an AutoResponded event notification

Tags: docusignapi

Every other recipient event that I have set up using the api webhooks has been successful, but "AutoResponded" doesn't seem to be behaving as I expected.  When I send an envelope to a totally undeliverable address, a DocuSign email is sent to the sender's address to say that it could not be delivered, but there is no event notice ever sent to my webhook url.

I set up this particular notification just like all of my others, this example is using only AutoResponded for testing purposes to try and isolate the problem.  Using the C# SDK:

```
envDefinition.EventNotification = new EventNotification()
{
    RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>() { new RecipientEvent("false", "AutoResponded") },

    IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "false",
    IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false",
    IncludeDocumentFields = "false",
    IncludeDocuments = "false",
    IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
    IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "false",
    IncludeTimeZone = "false",
    LoggingEnabled = "true",
    RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
    SignMessageWithX509Cert = "false",
    UseSoapInterface = "False",
    Url = webhookurl, //previously defined
};
```

If I poll for recipient status directly through the api, I will see an AutoResponded status there intermittently.  But in my full application, which has notifications set up for all other events, the XML that arrives will have the status of the bad email addresses as "Sent" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an account level settings to send `Auto Responded` status to Connect listener. You need to contact your DocuSign Account Manager to enable below setting from DocuSign Internal Admin.

```
Return Recipient Auto Responded Status in Connect/API
```